# Json schema array size reference

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a json schema with two entities `Foo` and `Bar`. `Foo` contains field `size` and `Bar` is an array. I want `Bar` array size to be equal to `Foo.size`. Is there any way to achieve this?

My approach is to use reference to `size` definition in `Foo`, but it is an invalid schema , since schema validator expects an integer after "minItems" and "maxItems" (I use https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/).

The approach:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {"$ref": "#/definitions/Foo"},
    "bar": {"$ref": "#/definitions/Bar"}
  },
  "required": ["foo", "bar"],
  "definitions": {
    "Foo": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "size": {"type": "number"}
        },
        "required": ["size"]
    },
    "Bar": {
        "type": "array",
        "minItems": "#/definitions/Foo/properties/size", // invalid
        "maxItems": "#/definitions/Foo/properties/size"  //invalid
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON Schema doesn't support data references this way, but it can be extended to do so.

I support this with [JsonSchema.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonSchema.Net/) and my [`data` vocabulary](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonSchema.Net.Data/).

Documentation can be found [here](https://gregsdennis.github.io/json-everything/usage/vocabs-data.html).